# How do I check the state of a thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have winform application where i am trying to play multiple videos and i am creating threading for that. My code is :

```
public String[,] vpath = new String[3, 7]; 
public Video[,] video = new Video[3, 7];
public static Thread[,] th = new Thread[3, 7];

public void playclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i, j;

        for (j = 0; j <= 7 - 1; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= 3 - 1; i++)
            {
                if (btnp[i, j].Capture)
                {
                    //play();

                    th[i, j] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(play));
                    th[i, j].IsBackground = true;
                    th[i, j].Start();
                }
            }
        }

    }

 public void play()
    {

            int i, j;
            for (j = 0; j <= 7 - 1; j++)
            {
                for (i = 0; i <= 3 - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (th[i, j].ThreadState == ThreadState.Running) // Having problem here
                    {
                        if (video[i, j].State != StateFlags.Running)
                        {
                            video[i, j].Play();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }      
    }
```

So with out that if statement it will run all the videos on single button press. But i want to run the particular video which the thread is in ..

pls help me guys

Comment: Is it not the case that on the first time through the loop which initializes the threads, play() will be called, and it will loop through all of the threads, but you've only initialized the first one?
Should the play() function not just deal with the thread that it is called from?

Comment: Which Video class is this? Is Play really synchronous (modal) ?

Comment: the thread will created only if the btnp(a dynamic button one of many) is pressed ... then the play() will be called.

Comment: but if i don't check the state of the thread then all my videos will start to play with only a single button which i dont want.. so i am checking the state there.. but i am getting an exception on that checking

Comment: This is a bit silly. Just pass the correct video to the play method.

Comment: @Rotem pls tell me how? i am trying this for a while

Comment: A little OT, but it seems to me you should create a class containing Path, Video and Thread. Will neaten up your code.

Comment: @dav will that help me to overcome this issue ??

Comment: @ArindamDas It will make your code easier to debug!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ThreadState is a bitmask-type property (enum has the [Flags] property, that's always the hint), so you don't check it directly using ==, you only need to check the relevant bit:

```
if ((t.ThreadState & ThreadState.Running) == ThreadState.Running) { ...
```

Read [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_ThreadState) about the meanings of the ThreadState values. From reading that and possibly the whole article, or whole book (highly recommended!) you'll also most likely notice that yours is probably not the ideal approach.
Not knowing your exact endgame though, it;s hard to suggest an exact one.

Comment: thanks for the ans @Tar but i am still getting the exception ...
    if ((th[i, j].ThreadState & ThreadState.Running) == ThreadState.Running){..}
and the exception is :
**NULL Reference Exception was unhandled**

Comment: well I was only talking about the 2dim array of threads. If you initialize the whole matrix (without the if (...Capture)) then you'll be getting no NullRef exceptions.

I'm sorry but this is the most basic stuff there is, if you're having problems with that you should most definitely not be trying to work with threads.

Comment: if  dont use the if(btnp[i,j].Capture)) then how i am going to check which button is pressed bcoz as i said before i have multiple btns which r dynamically created ... i think u r missing the basic concept dynamic buttons ... but thanks for the article and thanks for trying to help me

Comment: so add another check in the play() method where you check whether th[i, j] == null. In any case, please accept the answer.

Comment: This will always return true. Thread state "Running" is 0 And operation with Running always return 0, which is "Runing" state.

Answer (score 1):

As to why you are getting an exception, HaemEternal nailed that in his comment. You are only initializing one thread at a time, yet you are checking all of them. A `null` thread object does not have a `ThreadState` value.

May I suggest though, that you change your design altogether; 
There is no need to constantly check which thread was activated. You can change the signature of the `Play()` method to accept an `Object`, and you can pass the correct video to the method using that `Object`.

```
public void playclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i, j;

    for (j = 0; j <= 7 - 1; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= 3 - 1; i++)
        {
            if (btnp[i, j].Capture)
            {
                //play();

                th[i, j] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(play));
                th[i, j].IsBackground = true;
                th[i, j].Start(video[i,j]);
            }
        }
    }

}

public void play(object video)
{
    Video vid = video as Video; 
    if (vid.State != StateFlags.Running)
    {
        vid.Play();
    }        
}
```

An even better approach is to encapsulate these three elements in a single object that contains a `Video` object, a `Thread` object, and a path `string`.

If you own the `Video` class, you might even want to make the `Thread` and the `string` values fields of that class.
You might even want to create a field on your buttons of type of this new object, so each button will be associated with a button.
This is much more typical of object oriented design. There is no reason you should maintain four separate identically sized arrays, each of different type.

Comment: not working sir , I am getting exception at th[i,j].Start(video[i,j]);
and error at Video vid = video as Video;

Comment: invalid operation exception : The thread was created with a ThreadStart delegate that does not accept a parameter.

Comment: Odd, works for me. Try using `th[i, j] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(play));` instead of the current constructor.

Comment: Sounds as though you haven't changed something.

Comment: If you are referring to the error of `video` being null.. have you initialized it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @tar gives some hints but the code is wrong (as commented by @Sampath).

This come from the fact that `ThreadState` is implemented in a questionable strange way:
Normally a bitmask state is implemented using for example bit 1 for state `on` and the
same bit for the opposite `off`. This is not the case, in fact, for example, the `Running`
state has a 0 value, whereas the 1 value is taken by `StopRequested`.

So it is not wise to do a bit check.

A first approach would be to check for state with an or statement:

```cs
while (t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running ||
    t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Background)
    Application.DoEvents();
t.Join();
```

Keep in mind that if you start a process in background you will have the
`ThreadState.Background` enum value returned and not `ThreadState.Running`,
this is why I have put both.

The better and simpler approach is:

```cs
while (t.IsAlive)
    Application.DoEvents();
t.Join();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (th.ThreadState.Equals(ThreadState.Unstarted))
   th.Start();
```

Comment: Please explain code at some extent

Comment: if (startStop == true)
 {
  interruptHandler=true;
  if (th.ThreadState.Equals(ThreadState.Unstarted))
   th.Start();
 }
 else if (startStop == false)
 {
  if (th.ThreadState.Equals(ThreadState.Running))
  {
   interruptHandler = false;
  }
 }

Comment: Thanks I apricated it :) . Please update in answer and always give one to three lines on code to understand. it is good practice.